# Dictation is not working on my WPF application - need suggestion

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, voice-recognition, dictation

Trying to use free dictated words for voice recognition. But it is not working for me. Maybe someone can have a look.

Here it starts :

```
public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        recognizer = new SpeechRecognitionEngine();

        freeTextDictation();

    }
```

Here is the logic:

```
private void freeTextDictation()
    {
        GrammarBuilder startStop = new GrammarBuilder();
        GrammarBuilder dictation = new GrammarBuilder();
        dictation.AppendDictation();

        startStop.Append(new SemanticResultKey("StartDictation", new SemanticResultValue("Start Dictation", true)));
        startStop.Append(new SemanticResultKey("DictationInput", dictation));
        startStop.Append(new SemanticResultKey("StopDictation", new SemanticResultValue("Stop Dictation", false)));

        Grammar grammar = new Grammar(startStop);

        grammar.Enabled = true;
        grammar.Name = " Free-Text Dictation ";
        recognizer.LoadGrammar(grammar);

        recognizer.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();

        recognizer.SpeechRecognized += Recognizer_SpeechRecognized;
    }

    private void Recognizer_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
    {
        //MessageBox.Show(e.Result.Text.ToString());
        Console.WriteLine(e.Result.Text.ToString());
    }
```

The code is from microsoft website but I cant integrate it to get output.
Unfortunately nothing happens.

What can I do?